# Spring Cloud FeignClients doesn't work right during app start up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I use feign take some data from other micro service during app start up. I use a **@PostConstruct** method of a **@Service** bean to do this work, but the feign invork always timeout immediate when set **feign.hystrix.enabled** to true. When i set **feign.hystrix.enabled** to false, all correct. Config command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds to a big time useless. What problems may exist? The feign have not ready for work at this time?

images:
[maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF15k.png)[invork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEjob.png)[feign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evzBo.png)[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emnmT.png)
[property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhjkU.png)[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7tv0.png)

Comment: Add output of error message to your question description

Comment: Can you try to set hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled to false?

Answer (score 0):

when this happens, Spring documentation suggests you to use an ObjectProvider
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#early-initialization-errors

### Depending on how you are using your Feign clients you may see initialization errors when starting your application. To work around this problem you can use an ObjectProvider when autowiring your client.